# <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width funciona en PC y no en Android (explico dentro)

Tags: html5, css3, responsive

Estoy empezando con responsive con HTML5 / CSS3.
Estoy atascado con una cosa: entiendo sin problemas lo que hay que hacer para según la resolución se cargue un CSS u otro mediante media queries.

Yo hago:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minim-scale=1 maximum-scale=1" /
<link href="estilosGranResolucion.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 700px)"/>
```

Bueno, pues así, en chrome con opción desarrollador en PC, veo que perfecto, a los 700 pixels de anchura de la ventana, cambia el aspecto.
Pues si lo pruebo en un emulador de móvil en PC, el opera mobile emulator, veo que no cambia hasta los 1049 exactamente.

Y si pongo "min-width: 600px" no cambia hasta los 899 pixels. (en emulador móvil)

Y si pongo "min-width: 1000px" no cambia hasta los 1499 pixels. (en emulador móvil)

O sea, ni siquiera es constante el "offset" que se ve. Es como si se sumara siempre una cantidad a lo que yo le pongo, pero mientras más alta la resolución, más le suma antes de cambiar.

¿Por qué no cambia en el emulador de móvil a la resolución que debe cambiar y en PC sí?. También he probado en un móvil normal y pasa igual.

La verdad que estoy atascado con eso.

Cualquier pista la agradezco, gracias.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Veo lo que ocurre pero no sé cómo resolverlo

Si añado "   $(function(){alert(window.innerWidth);  
          alert(window.devicePixelRatio);
       alert(window.outerWidth);})  "           

Obtengo:                          

chrome PC: 1152     1      1152
opera mobile emulator (lo pongo a 1000 de ancho):  667  1.5  1000
chrome android (1080x1920): 360   3     360


Sé que la información del metadata es el problema, es la razón de que vaya mal en mi teléfono. 360x3 = 1080. Cómo puedo decirle a html5 que coja bien el ancho de pantalla?. La densidad de pixel es el problema.

Comment: He querido decir que devicePixelRatio es el problema.